# Seeking Insights: Access to Public Procurement Data

Tags: data-request, api

I'm currently working on a project that requires access to procurement data from various countries, and I'm exploring options for automated data retrieval. Can anyone help me identify which countries have published procurement data that allows for automated data retrieval? I'm specifically looking for data that can be accessed at least once a day, and I'm interested in all available methods for accessing the data, including APIs, bulk data downloads, and any other automated retrieval mechanisms.

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help."